# How to add a leafleat map when generating a pdf with thymeleaf?

Tags: spring-boot, leaflet, itext, thymeleaf

I have a spring boot app that generates a pdf with itext,
I'm trying to add a map when generating it.

I didn't find any way to add the leaflet.

my example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc">
<head>

    <title>Leaflet</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew==" crossorigin=""></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>
<body>


<div id="mapid" style="width: 100%; height: 750px;"></div>

<script th:inline="javascript">

    var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([0, 0], 4);

    L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
        attribution: 'Corona Virus'
    }).addTo(mymap);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, it is not possible to save as pdf the result of the javascript code. I suggest that you look how to get the map as an image and then you can pass the url of that image (or base64 encoding) to your template and convert to pdf.

Check example usages: http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/sdk/rest/export.html